# Trigger workflow execution based on the location of the changes in a mono repo

Tags: github, yaml, github-actions, workflow

As the title, I have a monorepo with several artifacts, each of which has a Dockerfile.

I plan to build the Dockerfile only when its folder has new incoming changes. And the changes could be introduced by either git-push or pull request. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

see https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-including-paths

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
    paths:
      - '**.js' # point this to your folder
  pull_request:
    paths:
      - '**.js' # point this to your folder
```

Comment: That's not what I need. I will have tons of services in my monorepo. The setting in `on` will globally set up the entire workflow so I need to manage each micro service, I will have to have workflows for each of them, which is not easy to manage.